# Dojo + clicking checkbox of the parent node in LazyTreeGrid should automatically make the child nodes checked How To

Tags: javascript, dojo, treegrid

I am working on `lazyTreeGrid` in `dojo` and so far I have managed to place `checkboxes`.

However,when I select a checkbox of a parent node or a folder , I need all the children nodes checkboxes to be automatically checked.How should I go about this?

This is what I have achieved so far.

http://jsfiddle.net/vay4R/

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You should fire a method to the `onChange` of those items. Implements checking all children in the method. And the `onChange` would execute recursively.

Comment: The `checkboxes` are inserted into the `lazyTreeGrid` by just using a `formatter`(creating a new `checkbox` element and appending it to the first column  of each row).
So,you see,an `onChange` event won't be capable of getting the `children` elements.

Comment: @harsha The `onChange` method would be executed when changed. When it is changed those `checkboxes` should already be children of it (already appended).